# Show form when install component in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, installation, components, joomla3.0

I want to show a small form with JavaScript when I install component like when we install our component then after installation I just want to show a form. I have created a file that is `script.commercial.php` and add this file in component xml see below my code:

**commercial.xml file**

```
<scriptfile>script.commercial.php</scriptfile>
<installfile>script.commercial.php</installfile>
```

**script.commercial.php**

```
    <?php
defined ('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
defined ('DS') or define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

function install () {
    $this->cmInstall();
}

function cmInstall()
{
    echo 'Show Form here.';
    echo '<span class="installScript" id="installScript"> Click Here..!! </span>';
}

$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript(JURI::BASE().'components/com_commercial/commercial.js');
```

But its not working and component install without showing this `Click` here or show form. How can I do this?

See Image, I want it to be like that:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below the joomla notes helpful for you

[This is the entire script.php file](https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Managing_Component_Updates_(Script.php))

Comment: that's for joomla 2.5, check the url you mentioned and also the tag

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: Thanks. Joomla2.5 same as Joomla3.x https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file/en